# Spotlight file path in Yosemite

Tags: spotlight

How do I expand the file path in Spotlight in Yosemite? In previous OS versions it would scroll to see the entire path, but now it only shows the end of the path preceded by ... Many of my files are PDFs of scientific literature and all I can see in the file path upon holding the command key is the end of the title.

Answer (score 1):

I found this workaround:

- open TextEdit.app
- switch to Plain Text (Format -> Make Plain Text or Cmd-Shift-T)
- search in Spotlight
- drag item into TextEdit.app window

It also works if you drag the file from Spotlight into a terminal window.

I am not sure if there is a more convenient way to do it. If there isn't, I hope Apple will fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

On Yosemite you need to command double-click the search result to access the enclosing folder